# trying to validate all fields have user input

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I want a validate a form serverside, I have all the individual fields being validated that all work, the only validation I cannot get to work is the validation that the form is not empty when submitted. In the following code after the form is submitted it is recieved in the if(isset($post statement. What I want to do is check fields are not empty, then if empty create an error message and then use header('location:) to goto a defined page with the error message in a session variable. If the validation returns that the fields are populated then the else part of the if statement goes through the individual validation (this all works as required). As you can see in the code I have tried different options to validate if the form fields are empty or not, these options i have tried are commented out, there is one in the first if statement and another in an if statement before hashing the password. I do have client side validation but as often mentioned in stack overflow it is good practise to do serverside validation.
So if anyone would be kind enough to help me resolve this I would be greatly appreciative

php code ***************************

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start();



error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$emailErr = $passwordErr = $password_matchErr = $email_existErr = $nameErr = $name_existErr = $confirm_passwordErr = $emptyErr = '';
$email = $name = $password = $confirm_password = $results = $row = $db_email = $db_id = $db_name = $db_password = '';


if (isset($_POST['name2'], $_POST['email2'], $_POST['paswword2'],$_POST['confirm_password2'])) {
//       $emptyErr = 'Please fill in all the Fields';
//       $_SESSION['emptyErr'] = $emptyErr;
////         header('location: ../join.php');
//echo $emptyErr;
//echo 'emptyform';
//       die();
}else{

$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    // Sanitize the data passed in 'email'


$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email2', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    // validate the data passed in 'email'
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

    // check if email is valid
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

        // Not a valid email
        $emailErr = "The email address you entered is not valid";
    }

    //Sanitize the data passed in 'password'
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    //validate the data passed in 'password'
    if (preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $password)) {
        } else {
        $passwordErr = "Password is invalid!<br>Please ensure your password is formatted as described when filling in the       form!";
        }

    //Sanitize the data passed in 'confirm_password'
$confirm_password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'confirm_password2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);      

    //check that password and confirm password match
    if ($password != $confirm_password) {

         // error matching passwords
    $confirm_passwordErr = "Your passwords do not match.<br>Please type carefully.";
     }

//   if($name == '' && $email == '' && $password == '' && $confirm_password = '') {
//       $emptyErr - 'Please fill in all the Fields';
//       $_SESSION['emptyErr'] = $emptyErr;
////         header('location: ../join.php');
//echo $emptyErr;
//       die();
//   }else{
//   }

    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
}
//echo 'test8';
//echo '<br>';
$query = ("SELECT * FROM signed_up WHERE (email = '$email') OR (name = '$name')");
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_BOTH)){

//echo 'test4';
//echo '<br>'; 
$db_id = $row['id'];
$db_name = $row['name'];
$db_email = $row['email'];
$db_password = $row['password'];
}
//echo $db_id;
//echo '<br>';
//echo $db_name;
//echo '<br>';
//echo $db_email;
//echo '<br>';
//echo $db_password;             



//check if user exsists, if confirmed go to the login page so user can login.
    if ($db_name === $name && $db_email === $email){
$regErr = 'User Already Exsists!<br>Please Login';
$_SESSION['regErr'] = $regErr;
header('location: ../login.php');
//echo $regErr;
die();
    }else

//echo $name;
//echo $db_id;
    if($db_name === $name && $db_email !== $email){
//echo 'test4';     
    $name_existErr = 'Username has to be Unique!<br>If this is your Username Please Login!<br>If this is not your Username Please Join with a different Username!';
//echo $name_existErr;  

            }
//echo $db_id;
//echo '<br>';
//echo $db_name;
//echo '<br>';
//echo $db_email;
//echo '<br>';
//echo $db_password;


            if($db_email === $email && $db_name !== $name){
    $email_existErr = 'Email has to be Unique<br>If this is your Email Please goto Login!<br>If this is not your Email check your Email and fill the Form in Again!';
//echo $email_existErr;
    }


            if($emailErr =='' && $passwordErr =='' && $confirm_passwordErr == '' && $email_existErr == '' && $name_existErr == '' && $emptyErr = ''){
//if all valid and no errors, register new user to the database.
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        $_SESSION['hash'] = $hash;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
echo 'no errors';
    header('location: register_user.inc.php');
    }else{
//if validation shows errors go back to join form.
//      $_SESSION['emptyErr'] = $emptyErr;
        $_SESSION['email_existErr'] = $email_existErr;
        $_SESSION['name_existErr'] = $name_existErr;
        $_SESSION['emailErr'] = $emailErr;
        $_SESSION['passwordErr'] = $passwordErr;
        $_SESSION['confirm_passwordErr'] = $confirm_passwordErr;
//echo $email_existErr;
//echo '<br>';
//echo $name_existErr;
//echo '<br>';
//echo $confirm_passwordErr;
//echo '<br>';
//echo $emailErr;
//echo '<br>';
//echo $password_matchErr;
//echo '<br>';
//echo $passwordErr;
header('Location: ../join.php');

    }

//echo $name;
//echo $email;
//echo $confirm_password;
//echo $password;
//echo $hash;
    ?>
```

end of php code ******************************

Html code ********************************

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dot Mov Home</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="/styles/home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/lemon:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/civem.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

<script src="/js/confirm_password__dbvalidate.js"></script>
<script src="/js/email_dbvalidate.js"></script>
<script src="/js/pswd_match.js"></script>
<script src="/js/pswrd_strength.js"></script>
<script src="/js/username_dbvalidate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function SwapDivsWithClick(div1,div2)
{
   d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
   d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
   if( d2.style.display == "none" )
   {
      d1.style.display = "none";
      d2.style.display = "block";
   }
   else
   {
      d1.style.display = "block";
      d2.style.display = "none";
   }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="video_container">
  <video muted autoplay loop >
    <source src="/video/South Dakota Badlands Scenic Byway 720p (Video Only)_1.3gp" type="video/3gp">
    <source src="/video/South Dakota Badlands Scenic Byway 720p (Video Only).webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="/video/South Dakota Badlands Scenic Byway 720p.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser. </video>
</div>

<header>

  <div class="upload"><a href="upload.html" title="Upload" target="_self">UPLOAD</a></div>
        <div class="view"><a href="view.php" title="View" target="_self">VIEW</a></div>
            <div class="spacer1"></div>

                <div class="search_bar">
                  <form action="/search_results.php" method="post" name="search_database" autocomplete="on">
                    <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search">
                  </form>


    </div>
                <div class="logo_text">.MOV </div>
                <div class="tagline">Motorcycle Online Video</div>
</a></header>
<main>

  <div id="login" style="display:block">




            <form method="post" action="includes/login.inc.php" id="loginform">


                <input name="email" type="email" id="email" form="loginform" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email">


                <input name="password" type="password" id="password" form="loginform" placeholder="Please Enter Your Password" title="Please Enter Your Password">


<div class="submit_buttons">
          <input type="submit" class="login_btn" form="loginform" formaction="includes/login.inc.php" title="Login" value="Login">

<a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('login','join')"><div class="join_but">Or Join</div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="forgotten_password">Forgotten Password</div>
        <div class="login_statements">
                      <div class="statement1">
                        <div class="by_joining">By Joining</div>
                        <div class="dot_mov">.MOV</div>
                        <div class="agree">You agree to our</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="statement2">
                        <div class="terms_link"><a href="terms.html" title="Terms of Service" target="_self">Terms of Service</a></div>
                        <div class="and">and</div>
                        <div class="service_link"><a href="privacy.html" title="Privacy Policy" target="_self">Privacy Policy</a></div>
                      </div>

              </div>
                    <div class="facebook_login">
                        <div class="facebook_icon"><img src="images/fb.png" class="fb_icon"></div>
                        <div class="fb_link">Login with FaceBook </div>
              </div>
    </form>
  </div>                  


  </div>


  <div id="join" style="display: none;">




    <form action="includes/register.inc.php" method="post" id="joinform">

                <input name="name2" type="text" id="name2" form="joinform" placeholder="Please Enter Your Username" title="Please Enter Your Username">
                <div id="user-name">
         <h4>Username must meet the following requirements!<br>If the Usename doesnt meet the requirements you will be required to fill in the form again!</h4> 

                <div id="name_result"></div>
                <div id="name_length" class="invalid">At least <strong>6 letters</strong></div>


                </div>


                <input name="email2" type="text" id="email2" form="joinform" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email" title="Please Enter a Valid Email">
                <div id="user-email">
         <h4>Email must be a valid Email format!<br>If the Email doesnt meet the requirements you will be required to fill in the form again!</h4>
                <div id="email_result">
                <div id="email_validate" class="invalid">Email Valid</div>
                <div id="emaildb_validate"></div>
</div>

      </div>


      <input name="password2" type="password" id="password2" form="joinform" placeholder="Please Enter Your Password" title="Please Enter Your Password">
<div id="pswd_info">
    <h4>Password must meet the following requirements!<br>If the Password doesnt meet the requirements you will be required to fill in the form again!</h4>
    <ul id="pswd_list">
        <li id="letter" class="invalid">At least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
        <li id="capital" class="invalid">At least <strong>one capital letter</strong></li>
        <li id="number" class="invalid">At least <strong>one number</strong></li>
        <li id="length" class="invalid">Be at least <strong>8 characters</strong></li>
    </ul>
</div>

                <input name="confirm_password2" type="password" id="confirm_password2" form="joinform" placeholder="Please Confirm Your Password" title="Please Confirm Your Password">
            <div id="user-confirm_password">
       <h4>Please Confirm Password<br>If the Passwords do not match, you wil be required to fill in the form again!</h4>     

      <div id="error" class="error"></div>
            <div id="confirm_match" class="invalid">Passwords Match</div>




      </div>

      <div class="submit_buttons2">
                    <input name="join_btn2" type="submit" id="join_btn2" form="joinform" formaction="includes/register.inc.php" " formmethod="POST" title="Join" value="Join">

<a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('login','join')"><div class="join_btn2">Or Login</div></a>
</div>


                                <div class="login_statements2">
                      <div class="statement1">
                        <div class="by_joining">By Joining</div>
                        <div class="dot_mov">.MOV</div>
                        <div class="agree">You agree to our</div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="statement2">
                        <div class="terms_link"><a href="terms.html" title="Terms of Service" target="_self">Terms of Service</a></div>
                        <div class="and">and</div>
                        <div class="service_link"><a href="privacy.html" title="Privacy Policy" target="_self">Privacy Policy</a></div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="facebook_login2">
                        <div class="facebook_icon"><img src="images/fb.png" class="fb_icon"></div>
                        <div class="fb_link">Login with FaceBook </div>
                        </div>
      </form>
  </div>                  




              </div>

  </div>
  <div class="scroll_container">
    <a data-scroll href="#body2"><div class="scroll_link">
      <div class="arrow"><img src="/images/arrow.png" alt="" class="arrow_icon"/></div>

      <div class="arrow3"><img src="/images/arrow.png" alt="" class="arrow_icon"/></div>
    Scroll Down</div></a>
  </div>







</main>

<div class="body2" id="body2">

  <div class="vid_grid">

    <div class="top_section">
        <div class="top_left_quarter"></div>
        <div class="top_right_quarter">
          <div class="top_right_left_quarter"></div>
          <div class="top_right_right_quarter"></div>
          <div class="top_right_bottom_left"></div>
          <div class="top_right_bottom_right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom_section">
      <div class="bottpm_left_top"></div>
      <div class="bottpm_left_bottom"></div>
      <div class="bottom_middle"></div>     
        <div class="bottom_left_quarter"></div>
        <div class="bottom_right_quarter"></div>
        <div class="bottom_right_top"></div>
        <div class="bottom_right_bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="/staff_picks.php"><div class="staff_picks">Staff Picks </div></a>


  </div>

</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <div id="breadcrumbs"><a href="/terms.html" title="Terms" target="_self">Terms</a> &vert; <a href="/privacy.html" title="Privacy" target="_self">Privacy</a> &vert; <a href="/about.html" title="About Us" target="_self">About Us</a> &vert; <a href="/copyright.html" title="Copyright" target="_self">Copyright</a> &vert; <a href="/cookies.html" title="Cookies" target="_self">Cookies</a> &vert; &reg &copy 2015</div><img src="/images/.mov.png" alt="" width="42" height="14" class="logo"/>
  <div class="social_media"><img src="/images/fb.png" alt="" width="30" height="30" class="fbicon"/><img src="/images/twitter.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="twittericon"/><img src="/images/googleplus.png" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="googleplusicon"/></div>



</footer>
<script src="/js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="/js/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        smoothScroll.init({
            speed: 1000,
            easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
            offset: 0,
            updateURL: true,
            callbackBefore: function ( toggle, anchor ) {},
            callbackAfter: function ( toggle, anchor ) {}
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

end of html code ***************************

[you can see the validation as is at this url](http://www.unitest.co.uk)
click on the join button for this form

Comment: `if (empty($_POST['var'])) { do_something(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Seriously don't dump pages and pages of code here expecting others to debug it.

You could some simple check like this:

```
$valid = true;
$requiredFields = array('name', 'age', 'email');

foreach ($requiredFields as $requiredField) {
  if( !isset($_POST[$requiredField] ) {
    $valid = false;
    break;
}

if (!$valid) {
   header('Location: /missingfields.php');
}
```

However, it would be better to *not* use a redirect, because all data that the user entered will be gone. You can output the same page again without processing the input and then pre-fill values in the HTML:

```
<input name="email" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])?>">
```

Comment: Note that the use of short tags are discouraged

Comment: As is using php for templating

Comment: I apologise for the amount of code, i have spent many hours and days doing this validation and tried to resolve this by myself before posting here. Also sometimes when questions are posted you get comments like "how can we understand what you are trying to do if you do not post both the php code and the html code associated with it". So it can be difficult what to post code wise and what not to post. I did specify the areas of the code I was having issues with and pointed out what I had tried clearly stating I had commented out my code I had tried. However all that said thankyou for your input

Comment: Mike what do you meanby short tags? and Bouke what do you mean by php for templating, i dont understand those comments

Comment: Mike is referring to the use of `<?=$var?>` in my example. This is embedding php using short tags. The long tags are like `<?php echo $var ?>`. If your server is not configured to use short tags, then the application won't work.

My response was a bit cynical, that outputing html straight from php is not a great idea. For example if $_POST['email'] wasn't set, php will generate errors. Also, you need to manually call a function to remove HTML-tags from the input. Templating engines such as blade, smarty, handlebars make this easier.

Answer (score -1):

You can validate each field if its empty by simple if condition like

```
if($_POST['fieldname'] == "")
return $error
```

Here is the edited code for first field you can do the same with other fields

```
        sec_session_start();



        error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

        $emailErr = $passwordErr = $password_matchErr = $email_existErr = $nameErr = $name_existErr = $confirm_passwordErr = $emptyErr = '';
        $email = $name = $password = $confirm_password = $results = $row = $db_email = $db_id = $db_name = $db_password = '';


        if (isset($_POST['name2'], $_POST['email2'], $_POST['paswword2'],$_POST['confirm_password2'])) {
            if($_POST['name2'] == "")
            {
               $emptyErr = 'Please fill in all the Fields';
               $_SESSION['emptyErr'] = $emptyErr;
                 header('location: ../join.php');
        echo $emptyErr;
        echo 'emptyform';
               die();
        }
        }else{

        $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            // Sanitize the data passed in 'email'


        $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email2', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

            // validate the data passed in 'email'
            $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

            // check if email is valid
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

                // Not a valid email
                $emailErr = "The email address you entered is not valid";
            }

            //Sanitize the data passed in 'password'
        $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


            //validate the data passed in 'password'
            if (preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $password)) {
                } else {
                $passwordErr = "Password is invalid!<br>Please ensure your password is formatted as described when filling in the       form!";
                }

            //Sanitize the data passed in 'confirm_password'
        $confirm_password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'confirm_password2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);      

            //check that password and confirm password match
            if ($password != $confirm_password) {

                 // error matching passwords
            $confirm_passwordErr = "Your passwords do not match.<br>Please type carefully.";
             }

        //   if($name == '' && $email == '' && $password == '' && $confirm_password = '') {
        //       $emptyErr - 'Please fill in all the Fields';
        //       $_SESSION['emptyErr'] = $emptyErr;
        ////         header('location: ../join.php');
        //echo $emptyErr;
        //       die();
        //   }else{
        //   }

            $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        }
        //echo 'test8';
        //echo '<br>';
        $query = ("SELECT * FROM signed_up WHERE (email = '$email') OR (name = '$name')");
        $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_BOTH)){

        //echo 'test4';
        //echo '<br>'; 
        $db_id = $row['id'];
        $db_name = $row['name'];
        $db_email = $row['email'];
        $db_password = $row['password'];
        }
        //echo $db_id;
        //echo '<br>';
        //echo $db_name;
        //echo '<br>';
        //echo $db_email;
        //echo '<br>';
        //echo $db_password;             



        //check if user exsists, if confirmed go to the login page so user can login.
            if ($db_name === $name && $db_email === $email){
        $regErr = 'User Already Exsists!<br>Please Login';
        $_SESSION['regErr'] = $regErr;
        //header('location: ../login.php');
        echo $regErr;
        die();
            }else

        //echo $name;
        //echo $db_id;
            if($db_name === $name && $db_email !== $email){
        echo 'test4';       
            $name_existErr = 'Username has to be Unique!<br>If this is your Username Please Login!<br>If this is not your Username Please Join with a different Username!';
        //echo $name_existErr;  

                    }
        //echo $db_id;
        //echo '<br>';
        //echo $db_name;
        //echo '<br>';
        //echo $db_email;
        //echo '<br>';
        //echo $db_password;


                    if($db_email === $email && $db_name !== $name){
            $email_existErr = 'Email has to be Unique<br>If this is your Email Please goto Login!<br>If this is not your Email check your Email and fill the Form in Again!';
        //echo $email_existErr;
            }


                    if($emailErr =='' && $passwordErr =='' && $confirm_passwordErr == '' && $email_existErr == '' && $name_existErr == '' && $emptyErr = ''){
        //if all valid and no errors, register new user to the database.
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['hash'] = $hash;
                $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
        echo 'no errors';
        //  header('location: register_user.inc.php');
            }else{
        //if validation shows errors go back to join form.
        //      $_SESSION['emptyErr'] = $emptyErr;
                $_SESSION['email_existErr'] = $email_existErr;
                $_SESSION['name_existErr'] = $name_existErr;
                $_SESSION['emailErr'] = $emailErr;
                $_SESSION['passwordErr'] = $passwordErr;
                $_SESSION['confirm_passwordErr'] = $confirm_passwordErr;
        echo $email_existErr;
        echo '<br>';
        echo $name_existErr;
        echo '<br>';
        echo $confirm_passwordErr;
        echo '<br>';
        echo $emailErr;
        echo '<br>';
        echo $password_matchErr;
        echo '<br>';
        echo $passwordErr;
        //header('Location: ../join.php');

            }

        //echo $name;
        //echo $email;
        //echo $confirm_password;
        //echo $password;
        //echo $hash;
            ?>
```

Comment: That will generate a warning if the variable is not set.

Comment: would i write that if statement individually for each field ie: if($_POST['fieldname'] == "")
return $error then another for the next, or would i write if($_POST['fieldname'] == "" && if($_POST['fieldname2'])

Comment: @Mike he is already checking the variable with isset condition and whether it is empty or not that is a nested if, better read the code before voting down

Comment: @user3370876 both of them are valid but I would recommend individual statement for each variable so that you can return a customized error to the user instead of sending a generic error message

Comment: @PavanJiwnani You're right. But still, it is rather redundant to check if they are set and then if they are `== ""` instead of all in one go with `if (empty($_POST['fieldname']))`.

Comment: I did try the if(empty(isset($_POST....... but couldnt get that to work, it seems as if its ignoring the element in the curly braces before the else and going to else stuff regardless

Comment: @user3370876 if you are using empty function then you don't need to check if the variable is set or not. empty function will return false if the variable does not contain any value or if it doesn't exist.